# How to set a default value for a method argument

Tags: crystal-lang

```
def my_method(options = {})
  # ...
end

# => Syntax error in ./src/auto_harvest.cr:17: for empty hashes use '{} of KeyType => ValueType'
```

While this is valid Ruby it seems not to be in Crystal, my suspicion is that it is because of typing. How do I tell compiler I want to default to an empty hash?

Comment: I'm confused, the accepted answer does not answer your question, however the answer you provided does. Why did you mark it as accepted?

Comment: I kind of had had two questions, how to set a default value (selected answer) and what does my error message mean (my answer about specifying the type).

Comment: But in your question you were already setting a default value, the only problem was the part you explained in your answer.

Comment: Correct, but I didn't realise that at the time. I didn't understand what the error message was telling me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a default argument (like in Ruby):

```
def my_method(x = 1, y = 2)
  x + y
end

my_method x: 10, y: 20 #=> 30
my_method x: 10        #=> 12
my_method y: 20        #=> 21
```

Usage of hashes for default/named arguments is totally discouraged in Crystal

(edited to include the sample instead of linking to the docs)

Comment: Good point, I found having a homogeneous Hash values to be too limiting anyway, so I will need to go the named argument route. Seems I'm still stuck in a Ruby 1.9 mindset!

Comment: The bulk of this answer is contained in the linked-to page.  The link is good, but the answer ought to stand on its own, especially since links tend go bad over time.  Could you please edit the answer to include more content?

Comment: @asterite Why are hashes and default/named arguments discouraged in Crystal? I've read through https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/literals/hash.html and https://crystal-lang.org/reference/conventions/coding_style.html and could not find reference to what you said. I'm not disagreeing that that's the case, I want to learn more.
If Hashes are discouraged how would you recommend handling `options` passed to an equivalent method to RoR's `content_tag` in Crystal https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Answer (score 5):

It seems the error has all the information I needed, I need to specify the type for the key and values of the Hash.

```
def my_method(options = {} of Symbol => String)
  # ...
end
```

It is quite clearly in the [docs](http://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/literals/hash.html) too.